# Best practice MVVM navigation using Master Detail page?

Tags: mvvm, navigation, master-detail, xamarin.forms

I want to follow the **MVVM** pattern **as much as possible**, but I don't know if I am doing the navigation quite well. Note that I am using a MasterDetail page and I want to maintain the Master page, changing only the Detail side when I navigate.

Here is the way I navigate from my **ViewModel**. In this example, from **ViewModelOne** to **ViewModelTwo**:

```
public class ViewModelOne : ViewModelBase
{
    private void GoToViewTwo()
    {
        var viewTwo = new ViewTwo(new ViewModelTwo());
        ((MasterView)Application.Current.MainPage).NavigateToPage(viewTwo);
    }
}
```

**MasterView** implementation:

```
public class MasterView : MasterDetailPage
{
    public void NavigateToPage(Page page)
    {
        Detail = new NavigationPage(page);
        IsPresented = false;
    }
}
```

**ViewTwo** implementation:

```
public partial class ViewTwo : PageBase
{
    public MenuView(ViewModelTwo vm)
        : base(vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**PageBase** implementation:

```
public class PageBase : ContentPage
{
    public PageBase(ViewModelBase vmb)
    {
        this.BindingContext = vmb;
    }
}
```

Is this the best approach (and best performance) for do the navigation? When I do some navigations, the app starts to run slower and maybe there is something I am not doing fine.

Is this the best approach for do the navigation showing always a MasterDetail page?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a lot of views you could use some PageFactory with caching like this: https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/ViewFactory

Answer (score 5):

I think you're certainly on the right track, however there are a few issues here:

Firstly, you should not be instantiating **Views** in your view model. As soon as your View Model becomes aware of the view, then you've pretty much broken the pattern.

```
var viewTwo = new ViewTwo(new ViewModelTwo());
```

Your *view creation* should be the responsibility of the master view. In fact, you don't even need to worry about **creating** views, as you can use a `DataTemplate` for that. I'll explain that later.

Firstly, we need to separate your **View Models** from the **Views**, here is what I propose:

You'll need some kind of base `class` or `interface` for your view models in order to keep things generic, you'll see why in a moment. Let's start out with a simple example:

```
public abstract class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event EventHandler OnClosed;        
    public event EventHandler OnOpened;

    //Don't forget to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
    public bool IsDisplayed { get; private set; } 

    public void Open()
    {
        IsDisplayed = true;

        //TODO: Raise the OnOpened event (Might be a better idea to put it in the IsDisplayed getter.
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        IsDisplayed = false;

        //TODO: Raise the OnClosed event.
    }
}
```

This of course is a very simple base view model, you can extend on this later, the main reason for this is to allow you to create a **master** view model which will be responsible for **displaying** your current *page*. Here's a simple example of a master view model:

```
public class MasterViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //Don't forget to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
    public ViewModel CurrentPage { get; private set; }

    public MasterViewModel()
    {
        //This is just an example of how to set the current page.
        //You might want to use a command instead.
        CurrentPage = new MovieViewModel();
    }

    //TODO: Some other master view model functionality, like exiting the application.
}
```

*Please note that `INotifyPropertyChanged` would probably be better in some kind of base class, instead of having to re-implement the same code over and over.*

Now the `MasterViewModel` is pretty simple, it just holds the current page, however the purpose of having the master is to allow for *application level* code to be executed, like closing the app, that way you're keeping this logic away from your other view models.

Right, now onto the good stuff.

Your **detail** has a relationship to it's parent, therefore it would make sense to say that it is the responsibility of the parent to manage it. In this case, your master-detail view model would look something like this:

```
public class MovieViewModel : ViewModel
{
    protected PickGenreViewModel ChildViewModel { get; private set; }

    public MovieViewModel()
    {
        ChildViewModel = new PickGenreViewModel();

        //TODO: Perhaps subscribe to the closed event?
    }

    //Just an example but an important thing to note is that
    //this method is protected because it's the MovieViewModel's
    //responsibility to manage it's child view model.
    protected void PickAGenre()
    {  
        ChildViewModel.Open();
    }

    //TODO: Other view model functionality.
}
```

So, now we've got some kind of view model structure here, I bet you're asking "What about the views?", well, that's where the `DataTemplate` comes in.

In WPF, it's possible to assign a *view* to a `Type`, for example, you can assign the `MovieView` to the `MovieViewModel` in XAML, like this:

```
xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:YourNamespace.Views"
xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:YourNamespace.ViewModels"

... 

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MovieViewModel}">
    <Views:MovieView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Ok great!, now to get the **Master View** to actually display the current page's view, you simply need to create a `ContentPresenter`, and bind it's `Content` to the `CurrentPage`. Your Master View will look something like this:

```
<Window 
    ...
    xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:YourNamespace.ViewModels">
<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:MasterViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentPage}"/>
</Grid>
```

To extend this further, it's not only the `MasterView` that needs to contain a `ContentPresenter` for it's *child*, it is also the `MovieView` which needs one for it's child `PickGenreViewModel`. You can use the same method again:

```
<Grid>
    <!-- The main view code for the movie view -->
    ...
    <Border Visibility="{Binding ChildViewModel.IsDisplayed, Converter=...">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ChildViewModel}"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

*Note: Use a boolean to Visibility converter to determine whether to display the child content.*

Using this method you don't have to worry about **instantiating** any views, as the `DataTemplate` and `ContentPresenter` handles that for you, all you need to worry about is *mapping* the view models to the appropriate view.

Phew! That was a lot to take in.

The main points to take away from this are:

1. You shouldn't be creating views in your view models, remember, **UI is UI, Data is Data**.
2. View model responsibilities lie with whoever owns them, for a parent-child relationship, it makes sense to let the parent manage the child, as opposed to a view model manager.

A final note is that there are certainly more than one other ways of achieving this, as I just mentioned, some kind of view and view model manager to be responsible for creating/removing views and view models.

Comment: wow, thank you a lot for your explanation, but I must say that I am using Xamarin.Forms...can I apply this approach?

Comment: Not a problem :-) Absolutely, the same principles apply.

Comment: I don't believe that Xamarin.Forms has the concept of a ContentPresenter which is where I have had problems with this.

Comment: It seems that Xamarin.Forms has ContentPresenter and also ContentView if you need this.